# mysql store search result as new table in memory

Tags: mysql

I am a novice, and I am wanting to know how to achieve this:

1million plus row in a table.

user runs a search, gets some results. I want to store this result in memory in a way, so that user can fire more SQL searches on this result. How is this done? I want this to go atleast upto 20 levels down.

in addition, lets say when I am 4th level down, can I have the previous levels intact for making fresh searches on them?

I also want to store some queries, which produce level X result, in a manner that it speeds the process in future (user do not have to make multiple searches to get to the result)

```
initial Table
|
|---1st search run on initial table (level 1)
      |
      |-----2nd search run on previously obtained result rows (level 2)
```

any help is highly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I've encountered DBAs who have thought of doing such.  The always decided it was too much work for too little gain.  But perhaps your case will be different.

Comment: You could use something like [materialized views](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-materialized-views) but in MySQL they would probably require some manual work (unlike postgresql).